# Automatic Checking of Incoming Emails

Tags: php, ajax, email, gmail, reverse-ajax

Is their a way to either code server side or client side to check new incoming replies to emails and register them in some way? I read upon using something called Reverse Ajax is this possibly the solution I should look into to code what I want.

Also another question is how do you keep track of email conversations? I took at a look at the hidden headers for emails sent and received and it seems that they carry a unique message id which could possibly be used to solve the problem I have.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split that into two tasks:

1. Checking for e-mails on the server
2. Communication between client and server

For 1: messages have a `Message-ID` header and optionally a `References` and an `In-Reply-To` header that allow you to put together *conversations*. Note that you also have to keep track of sent messages for that to work (because a reply that you receive has the `Message-ID` of a message that you sent in the `In-Reply-To` header).

For 2: the umbrella term seems to be [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: Sounds like I was going in the right direction. Basically it looks like I can use Comet to keep track of certain conversations and prevent it from checking all my emails stored. Hopefully thats what I got from what I read.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html
```

Here solution for poping mail, keeping track of new ones, each message has unique id we can use that to track new one.